# How to add URL component to current URL via a HTML button? (Django 2.1)

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a HTML button that is supposed to sort the search results by alphabetical order.

Button HTML code:

```
<a href="?a-z=True" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-{% if 'a-z' in request.GET %}success{% else %}secondary{% endif %}">A-Z</a>
```

`views.py`:

```
def query_search(request):
    articles = cross_currents.objects.all()
    search_term = ''
    if 'keyword' in request.GET:
        search_term = request.GET['keyword']
        articles = articles.annotate(similarity=Greatest(TrigramSimilarity('Title', search_term), TrigramSimilarity('Content', search_term))).filter(similarity__gte=0.03).order_by('-similarity')
    if request.GET.get('a-z') == 'True':
        articles = articles.order_by('Title')
```

Currently, the URL contains the keywords searched by the user. For example, if the user searches for "cheese," the URL will be `search/?keyword=cheese`. When I click the sorting button, the URL becomes `search/?a-z=True` and loses the keyword, which means that the sorting mechanism isn't sorting the search results based on the keyword. I think I need the URL to contain both the keyword and `?a-z=True` for the sorting mechanism to work on the search results. How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not specific to Django only, you can use javascript to do that:

Add a function that will get the current url and do the sorting function and call that function via `onclick`.
Then add the necessary param.

```html
<a href="#"  onclick="sort('a-z=True')"type="button" class="btn btn-outline-{% if 'a-z' in request.GET %}success{% else %}secondary{% endif %}">A-Z</a>
```

Then in your js part, you can check the url contains a `keyword` param, if not, just add the sort param.

```
function sort(foo) {
    let url = window.location.href;

    // check if current url includes a "keyword" param else add the sort as param
    if(url.includes("?") && url.includes("keyword")) window.location.href = url + "&" + foo;
    else window.location.href = url + "?" + foo;
}
```

This is just an idea and might not work since I never tried to run this.